# Applying Conditional Expectation Formula

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, expected-value, conditional-expectation

Suppose $X$ is a random variable, we want to find $\mathbb{E}(X\ |\ X>0)$. Is that equivalent to $\frac{\mathbb{E}(X\cdot \mathbb{1}_{X>0})}{\mathbb{P}(X>0)}$? From what I've seen online, it says that
$$\mathbb{E}(X\ |\ H) = \frac{\mathbb{E}(X \mathbb{1}_H)}{\mathbb{P}(H)}$$
where $H\in \mathcal{F}$ is some event in the $\sigma$-algebra. Thus, does this apply to my specific case? Additionally, if somebody could explain why the above formula works, that'd be great as well. Thanks.

Comment: Conditioning on a set is something of an abuse of notation (unless you are working with something like regular conditional probabilities). Conditioning is formally defined for when you condition on a sigma algebra. The set notation E[X | H] is essentially a shorthand for A in $E[X | \sigma(\{H \})]  = A 1(H) + B 1(H^c)$. 

It does apply to your situation. As to why that formula is true, if you integrate both $X$ and the right hand side of that expression on that set $H$, you will see that it is equal. I am writing this as a comment because I think someone else can write it more explicitly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes,  $X>0$ describes an event in the sigma-algebra generated by random variable $X$.

Thus indeed:$$\mathbb E(X\mid X>0)~=~\dfrac{\mathbb E(X\,\mathbf 1_{X>0})}{\mathbb P(X>0)}\raise{0.5ex}.$$

It is the expected value for $X$ measured over the event of $X>0$.